# t-sql convert datetime to time only with NO SECONDS

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, date, datetime-format

There are many t-sql CONVERT strings to produce quite a variety of date and or time strings.  But I cannot find the solution to needing no date and no seconds.

We want to return the time only from a datetime field, and eliminate the seconds.  It would not matter if the seconds were truncated or rounded, but we need to show no seconds.

```
    desired results- from any DATETIME field
     10:00 AM
     11:00 AM
      4:59 PM
```

any and all insights or suggestions appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this do it?

```
select CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100)
```

Just change out `GETDATE()` with your date variable.

Comment: very close!!!   we seem to have lost the am/pm designation... would that just be an alternative count?

Comment: Bingo !! Thank you very much... I will accept as the answer as soon as allowed...

Comment: @user761758 Thanks ! Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT LTRIM(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), GETDATE(), 100), 7))
```

Put your `DATETIME` field instead `GETDATE()`

Comment: Thank you for your reply .. Both answers work equally well for me.

Comment: @user761758 Glad to have been of help

Answer (score 0):

If you want a space then the AM /PM try this:

```
SELECT
Left(CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE() AS TIME),100),(len(CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE()  AS TIME),100))-2)) +' ' +  right((CONVERT(varchar(15),CAST(GETDATE()  AS TIME),100)),2) as NiceTimeAMPm
```

NiceTime
7:35 AM

3:00 PM